# Is it a bad practice to use 3 nested for loops?(or more!)

Tags: python, for-loop, architecture, nested

I've always wondered, what the best practices are to write code like a professional.

```py
for i in a[:]:
    print("i in for loop = %s" %i)
    print("\n")
    for x in range(2):
        for y in range(2):
            print(y)
print("A mask for this image can be of row * column config. 1x1, 1x2, 1x3, 2x1,...,3x3:")
```

Something tells me that my approach is never preferred.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that code? You could just replace the two inner loops with `print("0101")`. There is no general answer to your question. There are many alternatives to nesting loops. Depending on the intent of your code, these might be better alternatives or not.

Comment: I intent to make a movable window for linear filtering. I know this is abstract, I had this question since years. My teachers didn't entertain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the more nesting you have, the harder it is to read the code. In cases where you just want to do something for every `x` and `y` in some range, you can use `itertools.product`:

```py
import itertools
for x, y in itertools.product(range(2), range(2)):
    # Do something for every x, y
    print(x, y)
```

This way, you save one nesting, and it is still readable. This would even scale for an additional variable, e.g., `z`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a practice to avoid as much as possible because the number of nested loops and efficiency are directly connected.

If you have 1 nested loop complexity of algorithm is on average O(n)2 and 2 nested loops complexity increase to O(n)3.
If you have n elements in your data structure, say n=1000 O(n)2 is equivalent to 1000*1000 crossing over elements in you data structure  and O(n)3 1000*1000*1000 .Global complexity of algorithm it's depend also on eventual functions inside nested loops and can increase the final complexity.

Comment: I think you mean `O(n^2)` and `O(n^3)`. While this might be true in general, for the code in the question he only has two elements in the inner loops (`range(2)`).

Comment: you're right, global complexity depend on number of nested loops and optional functions inside them